# Galois covering induces an isomorphism on the level of (co)homology

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

The setting is the following : we have a smooth Galois cover of manifolds $p : Y \to X$, with (Galois) automorphism group $G$. Denote by $\Omega^*(X)$ and $\Omega^*(Y)$ the spaces of differential forms on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Somehow we want to express the cohomology of $X$ and $Y$ in terms of each other (motivating example : expressing the cohomology of projective space in terms of that of the sphere). [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522932/relations-between-covering-map-and-co-homology-groups) is strongly related, but here we are concerned with the technical details of the claim. For now we are only interested in homology.

Firstly we want a nice action of $G$ on $\Omega^*(Y)$. I think we can define one as follows : if $g$ is a covering space automorphism of $Y$, we can associate an automorphism $g^* : \Omega^*(Y) \to \Omega^*(Y)$. The action induced by $G$ is an action by such automorphisms.

Now denote by $\Omega^*(Y)^G$ the subalgebra of differential forms on $Y$ that are fixed by all automorphisms $g^*$.

> **Claim** : The induced map $p^*:\Omega^*(X) \to \Omega^*(Y)^G$ is an isomorphism.

This is where I encounter some problems. Firstly I can show that $p^*(\Omega^*(X)) \subset \Omega^*(Y)^G$ (the covering map $p$ and some automorphism $g$ of covering spaces form a commutative diagram. This gives us a "reverse" commutative diagram in homology with $p^*$ and $g^*$ from which we can deduce the inclusion). However the reverse inclusion seems difficult. We may have to use at some point the fact that $p$ is Galois ($Y=X/G$) but it gets more confusing as I go forward.

Moreover we should be able to find an explicit inverse for $p^*$ but I am unable to do so. Is my group action even reasonable ? Any help in either direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very quick sketch of the -hopefully correct- proof of the isomorphism (criticism is welcome and highly encouraged !). To avoid confusion "the action of $G$" will denote the standard action by automorphisms on Y, and "the action of $G^*$" will denote the action by the induced automorphisms $g^*$ on $\Omega^*(Y)^G$. We will try to build the inverse explicitly (locally, then gluing everything together).

- Take $U$ in $X$ a trivializing open set for $p$. Denote by $V$ one of the sheets in $Y|_U$. Take a form $\omega \in \Omega^*(V)^G$.
- Recall that forms in $\Omega^*(Y)^G$ are fixed by the action of $G^*$. Moreover, since $p$ is Galois, the action of $G$ on $Y$ is transitive. In particular, this gives us that the choice of $V$ doesn't matter, because $\omega$ will be the same on all the sheets.
- Now $p$ is a homeomorphism $V \to U$, so $p^{-1}|_U : U \to V$ exists and so does $(p^{-1}|_U)^*:\Omega^*(V)^G \to \Omega^*(U)$. By the previous point, this yields an isomorphism $\Omega^*(Y|_U)^G \to \Omega^*(U)$.
- We can repeat the construction for another trivializing open $U'$ in $X$. Forms upstairs in $Y$ will glue because they are defined globally, and thus they will glue downstairs in $X$. Thus we obtain an isomorphism $\Omega^*(Y)^G \to \Omega^*(X)$.

This result is interesting because it allows us to prove "half" of the following, more difficult result in cohomology.

> **Theorem** : The inclusion $i :\Omega^*(Y)^G \hookrightarrow \Omega^*(Y)$ induces a map $i^* : H^*(\Omega^*(Y)^G) \to H^*(Y)^G$ in cohomology. Moreover, if the group $G$ is finite, we have an isomorphism
>   $$
> H^*(X) \cong H^*(\Omega^*(Y)^G) \cong H^*(Y)^G
> $$

We can prove this with some technical work (considering "weighted" forms $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}g.\omega$). But this is for another time. As a direct application of this result, we can calculate $H^*(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}))$ thanks to that of $S^n$, as explained in the linked question.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "difficult" theorem above?